# How can I make changes to a JFrame GUI outside of the runnable in main?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, canvas

I'm currently learning Java GUI, and I'm making a Java program where you can edit shapes with text within a GUI. I've created a `JFrame` which contains a custom `MyCanvas` object and a text field. The idea is that the `MyCanvas` object has a `MouseListener` and will contain shapes, these shapes when clicked will enable the text field in the GUI so that the user can enter a new message to be displayed in the shape. However, I'm running the GUI with a `Runnable` inside the GUI class's main method, and I can't enable the text box from the `MyCanvas` class since it's outside of the `Runnable`. Could anyone help me how to make this possible?

Here's the basic structure of my code (pseudocode):

```
// GUI class
public class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private static MyCanvas c = new MyCanvas(); // canvas
    private static TextField editor = new TextField(); // text field

    public static void init() {
        // initialize GUI elements and disable text box
    }

    public static void enableTextBox() {
        // enables the text field
    }

    public static void disableTextBox() {
        // disables the text field
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // get message from text box
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Run the GUI frame
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                init();
                /* Add a RectTextBox (a Rectangle object with text inside,
                 * class defined elsewhere)
                 */
                c.addShape(new RectTextBox("Hello World");
            }
        }
    }
}

// Canvas class
class MyCanvas extends JPanel implements MouseListener {
    // ArrayList of blocks on the canvas
    ArrayList<RectTextBox> blocks = new ArrayList<RectTextBox>();

    // Ctor
    public MyCanvas() {
        // Initialize canvas and add MouseListener to this canvas
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // Paints all blocks on canvas
    }

    public void addShape(RectTextBox b) {
        // Adds the text box b to the blocks ArrayList
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        // check if any blocks from the ArrayList is clicked

        /* enables the text field from GUI to enter messages, then set the
         * message entered to the block
         */
    }
}
```

Comment: First thing to do is, step away from `static`, it's not helping your here.  The next thing is to maintain a reference between your `MyCanvas` and the controlling class.  You could then provide functionality in your `MyCanvas` which the controller class can call (such as setting the type of shape to use)

Answer (score 1):

So, you're off to a good start.  `MyCanvas` has functionality which can be called by other classes, for example, `addShape`...

```
// Canvas class
class MyCanvas extends JPanel implements MouseListener {
    // ArrayList of blocks on the canvas

    ArrayList<RectTextBox> blocks = new ArrayList<RectTextBox>();

    // Ctor
    public MyCanvas() {
        // Initialize canvas and add MouseListener to this canvas
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // Paints all blocks on canvas
    }

    public void addShape(RectTextBox b) {
        // Adds the text box b to the blocks ArrayList
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        // check if any blocks from the ArrayList is clicked

        /* enables the text field from GUI to enter messages, then set the
     * message entered to the block
         */
    }
}
```

Next, you need to pass a reference of `MyCanvas` to those classes which want to perform some operation on it, as a "really" basic example...

```
public class EditorPane extends JPanel {
    private MyCanvas canvas;

    public EditorPane(MyCanvas canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
        // Build UI as required
    }
}
```

Then when `EditorPane` wants to make a change, it can use `canvas` to call the methods it needs to.

Then, we you build your UI, you would make an instance of `MyCanvas`, pass that reference to both the `EditorPane` and add it to the UI, for example...

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        MyCanvas canvas = new MyCanvas();
        EditorPane editor = new EditorPane(canvas);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(canvas);
        frame.add(editor, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

Now, personally, I'd fold much of this up into `interface` to prevent `EditorPane` from doing more to `MyCanvas` then it should, but that's a topic for another day ;)

Comment: Thank you very much! With your solution, is there any way I can have the canvas also know about the editor panel? I want to make it so that the editor panel only turns on when you click on one of the shapes.

Comment: Probably not worth effort.  I'd simply have it so that when you click a shape, one of things it does it "turns on" the canvas